# No Method Error for user on a new string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having some trouble with a Rails project of mine. I am trying to place validations for new topics. It should have a minimum of four characters for the topic, but I receive an error for users. Here is my error:

```
2.2.0 :019 > t=Topic.new
 => #<Topic id: nil, name: nil, public: nil, description: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.2.0 :020 > t.valid?
NoMethodError: undefined method `user' for #<Topic:0x007ff53fb9e268>
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/validator.rb:149:in `block in validate'
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/validator.rb:148:in `each'
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/validator.rb:148:in `validate'
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/validations/presence.rb:5:in `validate'
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:450:in `public_send'
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:450:in `block in make_lambda'
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:189:in `call'
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:189:in `block in simple'
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:190:in `call'
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:190:in `block in simple'
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:190:in `call'
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:190:in `block in simple'
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:190:in `call'
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:190:in `block in simple'
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
... 21 levels...
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.4/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.4/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.4/lib/spring/application.rb:183:in `block in serve'
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.4/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `fork'
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.4/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `serve'
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.4/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.4/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.4/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/spring-1.3.4/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/ericpark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

My topics controller:

```
class TopicsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @topics = Topic.all
    authorize @topics
  end

  def new
    @topic = Topic.new
    authorize @topic
  end

  def show
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
      @posts = @topic.posts
    authorize @topic
  end

  def edit
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
     authorize @topic
  end

  def create
    @topic = Topic.new(topic_params)
     authorize @topic
     if @topic.save
       redirect_to @topic, notice: "Topic was saved successfully."
     else
       flash[:error] = "Error creating topic. Please try again."
       render :new
     end
  end

  def update
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
     authorize @topic
     if @topic.update_attributes(topic_params)
       redirect_to @topic
     else
       flash[:error] = "Error saving topic. Please try again."
       render :edit
     end
  end

  private
  def topic_params
    params.require(:topic).permit(:name, :description, :public)
  end
end
```

Topics Model:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  belongs_to :user

  validates :name, length: {minimum: 5}, presence: true
end
```

I am not sure why it states NoMethodError: UNdefined method 'user,' I didn't think topic needed a user method since it is not one of the attributes of topic. Any help and explanation would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have `belongs_to :user` in your `Topic` class. Does the `User` class exist?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was also wondering is there a way to inherit the association instead of stating belongs_to? For example if I wanted Post to be associated to Topic. SInce topics already has a user_id, how would I allow Posts to inherit that attribute? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean a many to many association between `posts` and `topics`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have the User model missing.

*app/models/user.rb*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :topics
  has_many :posts
end
```